# How can I use only specific ZapierNLA Tools in my Agent

Tags: zapier, langchain, py-langchain

How can i use only specific tools from ZapierToolkit. I want to select a specific tool out of the available ones based on the output of LLMChain and then pass only that tool to the agent. If i provide all the tools at once then the query becomes very long.

```
    zapier = ZapierNLAWrapper()
    toolkit = ZapierToolkit.from_zapier_nla_wrapper(zapier)
    tools = toolkit.get_tools()
    agent = initialize_agent(tools=tools, llm=llm, memory=memory, agent="conversational-react-description")
```